# How to: Publish selected article on Facebook wall at a time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

To be specific... Here's what i'm doing.

I am getting success in posting a single article. Using the following code.

#### *window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');*

Here "u" is the url of the article that i want to publish.
so if i pass www.google.com it fetches the content and displays it in a pop up window.

now what i want to do is.

I want to publish more than one link at a time.
Say select the articles from the list and then press the share button.
All the selected articles should get published at a time to the my wall or to the selected page.

I tried using for loop in php but in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because it would need to popup multiple share dialogs which wont work or at least is not a good idea via the JavaScript API. It is kinda spammy and the Facebook terms of service say the user should be prompted for original text / status when sharing a link. You could have them authorize your application for publish_stream permissions and then publish several links at a time with PHP code but again you run the risk of being marked as spam.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
So there's no way it can be done.?
I have played around with extended permissions with offline_publish..
But didn't worked the way i wanted... @OffBySome

Comment: I was getting it published with the user who is logged-in in FB, but i wanted it to be published as admin of that page. did you get it ?